# How to validate a font to be used with XeLaTeX, fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{jizura3b}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The single character in the document should be displayed using the font as indicated; it is a font i have created myself using https://github.com/loveencounterflow/svgttf, which in turn uses https://github.com/fontello/svg2ttf to turn an SVG file into a TTF font.

Indeed, this works as expected on OSX and Tex Live 2013 and 2014; however, on Ubuntu using Tex Live 2015, i get a core dump:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex)
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
[1] (./test.aux) )
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Error 35584 (driver return code) generating output;
file test.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Googling for the error number, `35584`, would indeed indicate the error might be font-related, and this is exactly the conclusion i have come to, even though multiple apps on OSX and the Ubuntu Font Viewer all display the font fine without errors.

OTOH, this is not the first font i find that works OK everywhere except in XeLaTeX.

**Given a font that XeLaTeX (or fontspec?) has troubles with, what are the recommended steps to test whether the fault is with XeLaTeX/fontspec or with the font?**

Related: **How to find out exactly what detail in the font makes LaTeX derail?**

As an aside, I think that regardless whether the font is valid or not, LaTeX should not segfault but terminate with a helpful error message and an error code. As far as I can see no error code was emitted, so my tool chain ignored that problem at first; the only formal sign of there being a problem was that `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` was sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: You can start determining whether it’s `xetex` or `fontspec` by trying to compile your MWE with `luatex`. If that fails too, you can get some idea whether `fontspec` is at fault by trying to use the font directly with `luaotfload`. Also try the `fontlint` tool that comes with Fontforge.

Comment: Possibly you’ll be interested in https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86piska.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thérèse thanks for your tips indeed! I waited a bit too see whether more people would chime in, but since no other input has been made, I'll just report how I managed to resolve the issue.

First, replacing `xelatex` with `luatex` does indeed work. The downside of that, however, is that `luatex` takes quite some while longer for a run than does `xelatex`, so I looked further and tried `fontlint`; based on that, i used `fontforge` to repair the broken font. For comparison, first have a look at `fontlint`'s outputs for the broken and the working font:

```
$ fontlint <path to broken font>
Copyright (c) 2000-2012 by George Williams.
 Executable based on sources from 14:57 GMT 31-Jul-2012-ML.
 Library based on sources from 14:57 GMT 31-Jul-2012.
Missing required table: "post"
Validation jizura3b ...Failed
  Self Intersecting Glyph
  Wrong Direction
  Missing Points at Extrema

$ fontlint <path to working font>
Copyright (c) 2000-2012 by George Williams.
 Executable based on sources from 14:57 GMT 31-Jul-2012-ML.
 Library based on sources from 14:57 GMT 31-Jul-2012.
Validation jizura3b ...Failed
  Self Intersecting Glyph
  Wrong Direction
  Missing Points at Extrema
```

You can see that while more than a single problem was reported, the essential one is really `Missing required table: "post"` (I'd really like FontForge repair all the defects, but didn't manage to get that).

Now the easiest way to make FontForge repair a font is to prepare a very short script in FontForge's scripting language, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/fontforge -lang=ff
Print("Reading "+$1);
Open($1);
Generate($1:r + ".rewritten-by-fontforge.ttf");
```

Save that under any name you like, make the file executable, call it with the path to the broken font, and presto.